# Retrieve coordinates from the photos codename one

Tags: codenameone, photo, coordinate

I'm asking if there is a way to retrieve the location coordinates from the photos taken with the smartphone.
does it exist properties or methods for doing it?

Thanks in advance for any answers.
Luca

Answer (score 0):

We don't currently have an API to read image or media file meta-data in Codename One. This should be doable with native interfaces or simple parsing of the image file headers but there is no current standard API.

Comment: Thank's anyway, bye.